# Angularjs dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a simple dropdown, everything looks good but it doesnt work. Here is the code

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

          $scope.colors = [
{name:'black', shade:'dark'},
{name:'white', shade:'light'},
{name:'red', shade:'dark'},
{name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
{name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
];

});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">   
 <span class="nullable">
<select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors">
<option value="">-- choose color --</option>
</select>
</span><br/>
</div>
```

Here is the plunker for it 
http://plnkr.co/edit/LCbabCglUQmGHQCXx1Pa?p=preview

Comment: I dont see angular.js included anywhere.

Comment: You mean in plnkr? There is a script.js

Comment: In addition to what @CodeHater said, your `ng-model` should be assigned to `colors` not `color`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сode is working. You forgot to include the angular library.

I create JSFiddle, which demonstrates correct work your select.
[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2342/)

```
<select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors">
    <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented your code in my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl%3aFrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f?p=preview) have a look onto this. Working now!!

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a scope variable color to set the value of the selection to. 
your plunker also doesn't seem to have angular loading, though im not really sure how to do it on plunker...

```
<select ng-model="color" ...>
```

is trying to assign the selected array index to

```
$scope.color
```

which doesn't exist

i tweaked your plunker example and made a fiddle with it working
http://jsfiddle.net/pixelchemist/teMUR/

Comment: i should add its possible to create that color by defining it that way in the markup but not suggested